# How to customise a color scheme to your own taste in Microsoft Outlook 2019?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, colors, desktop-customization, xml, microsoft-outlook-2019

Microsoft Outlook 2019 provides (only) four color schemes to choose from.
How can I manully fully customise one of these color schemes to my own taste?

For example I want to make the current day background yellow, and the current week background purple.

Thanks!

[image: he]

Comment: @Perry What do you mean by `"set one color at a time"`. Do you mean *A)* `"one theme that has to be chosen from one of the 4 presets"` or do you mean *B)* `"each color can be fully manually customised, one at a time"` ?

Comment: A. We can only choose color from the View > Color. And same background color of one calendar. For example, you choose Blue. And then you will see dark blue color for today and light blue color for other days.

Comment: Thanks @Perry that was a very nice hint! I did not know that. That kind of solves my problem! If you write this as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that we can only set one color at a time. You can check the details in [this official article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-appearance-of-your-calendar-84efcbbb-52a5-4aab-9fbc-7e0f0520bb42)

You can visit the [Outlook user voice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/)to submit your feedback

We can only choose color from the View > Color. And same background color of one calendar. For example, you choose Blue. And then you will see dark blue color for today and light blue color for other days